# BigQuery GAP data: Products purchased by customers who purchased product A

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I was following the example:

**Products purchased by customers who purchased product A in the BigQuery cookbook.** 
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/4419694?hl=en#query7_ProductsPurchasedByCustomersWhoPurchasedProductA

**INFO:** I am using Enhanced E-commerce in Google Analytics Premium hence the v2 in the field names. The Xes replaces the orginal dataset and date of the table I am using

**QUESTION:** Now the following query gives me an inflated number for quantity of each other_purchased_products. I was expecting to see the total of all other products bought that the customers who had a transaction that included blue footballs. If I look at all of the transactions in Google Analytics Premium that included blue footballs the number of other products they bought does not add up?

```
SELECT hits.product.v2ProductName AS other_purchased_products, COUNT(hits.product.v2ProductName) AS quantity
FROM [XXXXXXX.ga_sessions_XXXXXXXX]
WHERE fullVisitorId IN (
  SELECT fullVisitorId
  FROM [XXXXXXX.ga_sessions_XXXXXXXX]
  WHERE hits.product.v2ProductName CONTAINS 'blue footballs'
   AND totals.transactions>=1
  GROUP BY fullVisitorId)
 AND hits.product.v2ProductName IS NOT NULL
 AND hits.product.v2ProductName != 'blue footballs'
GROUP BY other_purchased_products
ORDER BY quantity DESC;
```

If anyone has any clues it would be fantastic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention how far off these counts are, but one thing I notice is that your query uses the `COUNT` function which is a statistical approximation. This may account for the differences you are seeing.

If you want an exact count, use `EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT`. See https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#exact_count_distinct.

Comment: Thanks for reaching out Michael. The result now using exact count gives me count of 1 in other_purchased_products by product even transactions not including 'blue footballs' but after looking at the orders by transaction id in google analytics I see products that were not as part of a transaction were "blue footballs" was part of an order.  Maybe I should rethink and in sudo code say: give me all transactionIds where product name = "blue footballs". Then use the list of ids to query the same data set / table again & join by transaction ids? Do you know? Thanks m